# How to create a layout in HTML as in the attached link

Tags: html, layout

Guys i was working on the design of website that i will publish. I saw this page http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US of Microsoft‘s Surface. I‘m wondering how they made these colored layouts. I tried to create a layout using `<p></p>` property than i wrote any text in it that i make the text color and the background-color the same color than i used padding property to do expand the `<p></p>` but the problem is still there a blank spaces around the edges of the page. If you have any suggestions i would be more than thankful.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get a helpful response if you post your relevant code (HTML and CSS, in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i fully understand but from what you are saying could it be the body margin and padding have not been set to zero

```
<style>

body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This is what i‘m looking for. Edges of the page have been removed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey no point in marking down something you have not tried to fix. Im glad i guessed right...

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div>` to create the colored sections, for the inside you could use tables (avoid) or a fluid grid system like unsemantic.